# Proper GPUOffScreen projection matrix from viewport

Tags: python, 3d-view, gpu, matrix

How to get proper `GPUOffScreen` projection matrix from viewport?

API docs [have example](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/gpu.html#rendering-the-3d-view-into-a-texture) only for camera.
I tried using `view_matrix` and `perspective_matrix`, but that does not seem to work.

```
gpu.matrix.load_matrix(region_3d.view_matrix.inverted())
gpu.matrix.load_projection_matrix(region_3d.perspective_matrix)
```

Here is full script, it supposed to display silhouettes for all objects in the scene:

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from gpu_extras.presets import draw_texture_2d


def get_regions():
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        for area in window.screen.areas:
            if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
                r3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d
                for r in area.regions:
                    if r.type == "WINDOW":
                        return r, r3d


region, region_3d = get_regions()
offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(region.width, region.height)

with offscreen.bind():
    fb = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get()
    fb.clear(color=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

    with gpu.matrix.push_pop():
        gpu.matrix.load_matrix(region_3d.view_matrix.inverted())
        gpu.matrix.load_projection_matrix(region_3d.perspective_matrix)

        for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            me = ob.to_mesh()
            me.transform(ob.matrix_world)
            me.calc_loop_triangles()

            points = [v.co for v in me.vertices]
            indices = [tri.vertices for tri in me.loop_triangles]

            shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin("UNIFORM_COLOR")
            shader.bind()
            shader.uniform_float("color", (1.0, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
            batch = batch_for_shader(shader, "TRIS", {"pos": points}, indices=indices)
            batch.draw(shader)

            ob.to_mesh_clear()


def draw(self, context):
    gpu.state.blend_set("ALPHA")
    draw_texture_2d(offscreen.texture_color, (0, 0), region.width, region.height)
    gpu.state.blend_set("NONE")


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (None, None), "WINDOW", "POST_PIXEL")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
with gpu.matrix.push_pop():
    gpu.matrix.load_matrix(region_3d.view_matrix.inverted())
    gpu.matrix.load_projection_matrix(region_3d.perspective_matrix)
```

with:

```
with gpu.matrix.push_pop():
    gpu.matrix.load_matrix(region_3d.view_matrix)
    gpu.matrix.load_projection_matrix(region_3d.window_matrix)
```

Relevant section in the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.perspective_matrix):

> Current perspective matrix (window_matrix * view_matrix)

So you accidently did $W \cdot V \cdot V^{-1} = P \cdot V^{-1}$

but you just want $W \cdot V = P$

This perspective is already "through the window".
You can convince yourself with trying:

```
with gpu.matrix.push_pop():
    #gpu.matrix.load_matrix(region_3d.view_matrix.inverted())
    gpu.matrix.load_projection_matrix(region_3d.perspective_matrix)
```

which works as well. But the view matrix should potentionally not be merged on the projection stack to avoid other problems.